# Non Persistent Quartz scheduler in java

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

We have an application deployed in a clustered environment. Every 5 minutes our application sends a ping operation to all other applications connected to it. We have used non-persistent Quartz scheduler in order to do this work.

The problem is that in a clustered environment only one node is doing this activity(ping operation). Are there any references or any sample code for this?  (This is a plain servlet application.)

Comment: I've updated some of the phrasing of your question to make it easier to read - however I'm not sure about the meaning of the first sentence.  Are you saying that only one node **is sending** pings (and you want the rest to)?  Or that your **requirement** is to have only one node send pings, but at the moment every node is?

Comment: Yes only one node is performing the ping operation i want all other nodes to perform the ping operation (cluster environment)

Answer (score 0):

Since all nodes are working in a cluster, every job runs on just a single machine (most idle one). This is the reason you use clustering. But you want all machines to run given job independently, not being aware of other cluster nodes. Basically, you don't need Quartz (cluster) at all!

Enough is to use [`ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29):

```
final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

final Runnable pinger = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //send PING
    }
};
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(pinger, 5, 5, MINUTES);
```

Just run this code on every machine and use Quartz where you need it.

Comment: I tested the above code in cluster environment and it worked perfectly fine. Now i am having one more challenge here . Is there any way to start and stop these schedulers whenever i want ?

Comment: @RajeshGupta: please open another question for that and feel free to comment with follow-up link